# How can I pass multiple variables as URI paths in a BQ stored procedure?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am new to BQ and trying to load multiple csv files to temp table in BQ from multiple subfolders from GCS, and need to use variable as a path in uri. Excluded the load script since getting error in uri's part.

**Query error:** Found unsupported function call 'ARRAY[...]'; failed to set 'uris' in OPTIONS()

**Code Snippet**

```
DECLARE my_bucket_path STRING;  
DECLARE sub_dir_1 STRING;
DECLARE sub_dir_2 STRING;
DECLARE sub_dir_3 STRING;

SET my_bucket_path = 'gs://my_bucket';
SET sub_dir_1 = 'sub_dir_val1';
SET sub_dir_2 = 'sub_dir_val2';
SET sub_dir_3 = 'sub_dir_val3';

--Create external data source referencing the GCS Bucket
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.temp_table (
col1 STRING,
col2 FLOAT64,
col3 FLOAT64,
col4 INT64,

) OPTIONS (
format = 'csv',
uris = [my_bucket_path||'/'||sub_dir_1||'/'||sub_dir_2||'/'||sub_dir_3||'/*.csv'],
skip_leading_rows = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery doesn't support direct concatenation of strings in the `uris` option of the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement. However, you can achieve this by using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement to create the table with a dynamic URI path:

```sql
DECLARE my_bucket_path STRING;  
DECLARE sub_dir_1 STRING;
DECLARE sub_dir_2 STRING;
DECLARE sub_dir_3 STRING;

SET my_bucket_path = 'gs://my_bucket';
SET sub_dir_1 = 'sub_dir_val1';
SET sub_dir_2 = 'sub_dir_val2';
SET sub_dir_3 = 'sub_dir_val3';

-- Create the dynamic URI path
DECLARE uri_path STRING;
SET uri_path = CONCAT(my_bucket_path, '/', sub_dir_1, '/', sub_dir_2, '/', sub_dir_3, '/*.csv');

-- Create a SQL string for creating the external table
DECLARE create_table_sql STRING;
SET create_table_sql = CONCAT('
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.temp_table (
  col1 STRING,
  col2 FLOAT64,
  col3 FLOAT64,
  col4 INT64
) OPTIONS (
  format = "csv",
  uris = ["', uri_path, '"],
  skip_leading_rows = 1
)');

-- Execute the SQL string
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_table_sql;
```

We first create a `uri_path` variable by concatenating the strings. Then, we create a `create_table_sql` variable that contains the SQL statement to create the external table with the dynamic URI path. Finally, we use the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement to execute the SQL string and create the table.